# Google PlacePicker Api with Autocomplete Search Bar

Tags: android

Isn't there any library or any other way where I can add Search bar in Google Maps PlacePicker Api Fragment where I can get the functionality of autocomplete textview with maps pointing to that location and nearby places for that location.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I was using old version of play services so I got this error but after updating it to 8.3 I got thr autocomplete search bar

Answer (score 0):

The PlacePicker actually supports this, though at the time of writing this, the documentation does not yet describe it. It likely depends on the Play Services version you have installed on your device and I can confirm that the search and auto complete bar exists in 8.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with PlacePicker too. But it worked perfectly on Android 4.4 and above. But on my HTC Desire 500 (Android 4.1.2), there is no search bar. I tried to update maps library to 8.4.0 and updated the lasted version of Google Place Services on my phone. But it didn't work.